# Keras Early Stopping Patience

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing early stop manually to train model using 'train_on_batch'.

If the standard is Validation Loss, is it right to stop the training, if the Validation Loss is not lower than the previous Minimum Validation Loss during the Patience Epoch?

In other words, if the Validation Loss is larger than the Validation Loss of the previous epoch, training terminate when Minimum Validation Loss does not appear during the Patience Epoch?

Thanks

Comment: Due to how stochastic gradient descent works it is usually sensible to have some level of patience in your early stopping, i.e. *if val_loss hasn't decreased for n epochs stop training*.  It is controlled by `patience` parameter in Keras EarlyStopping.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You mean early stopping module comparing best(minimum) loss and current epoch loss?

Comment: Yes, this is how EarlyStopping works.